# PM SYSTEM - i can't open the specific message

Tags: php, mysql

I'am new in the php language. Can somebody help me? I made an personal message system, with one mysql tablet. the mysql is working.  my inbox is working, i can see my messages. but when i click to one message, always the first message contest come on. how can i open the specific message? 
These are my codes:

inbox.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require "database.php";
$userfinal=$_SESSION['session_name'];

// get the messages from the table.
$get_messages = mysql_query("SELECT message_id FROM messages WHERE to_user='$username' ORDER BY message_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$get_messages2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='$username' ORDER BY message_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($get_messages);
// display each message title, with a link to their content
echo '<ul>';
for($count = 1; $count <= $num_messages; $count++)
{

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get_messages2);
    //if the message is not read, show "(new)" after the title, else, just show the title.
if($row['message_read'] == 0)
{
    echo '<a href="read_message.php?messageid=' . $row['message_id'] . '">' . $row['message_title'] . '</a>(New)<br>';
}else{
echo '<a href="read_message.php?messageid=' . $row['message_id'] . '">' . $row['message_title'] . '</a><br>';
}}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<form name="newmsgfrm" method="post" action="new_message.php">';
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Send a New Message">';
 echo '</form>';

echo '<form name="backfrm" method="post" action="index.php">';
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Back to Home">';
 echo '</form>';
?>
```

read_message.php

```
<?php



// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('db') or die('Could not select database');


// Performing SQL query
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = '$username' " ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

// Printing results in HTML

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['from_user'];
echo $row['message_title'];
echo $row['message_contents'];
 ?>
```

with the read_message.php i can read my message,but just the first :/ What should i do to read the specific message? Thanks for the help :) (sorry for my english..)

(i guess  i have to do something with the messages id, but i dont know what:/ )

Comment: Why are you doing two queries? The number of rows in `$get_messages` is the same as `$get_messages2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_message.php` needs to use the `messageid` parameter to read the specific message requested:

```
$messageid = sprintf("%d", $_GET['messageid']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = '$username' AND message_id = $messageid" ;
```

Comment: wow thanks!! now it is working :) but if i read it, the 'new' word isnt disappear ( it is in the inbox, afthe the message title) do u have a soloutin for this too? :)

Comment: The `read_message.php` script needs to perform an `UPDATE` to set the `message_read` column to 0.

Comment: Do you have the slightest idea what you're doing? It doesn't seem like you know anything about computer programming or databases.

Comment: not much, i am a newbie. i used to copy and paste tempatles. thanks for your help:)

Comment: You won't become a programmer by cutting and pasting code, any more than you could become a chef simply by following recipes in cookbooks.

Comment: i know :/ but i just have a few days, to make a website, bc its is just my hobby. but if i will have time i will learn about it :) (i know there are lot of php-studying-sites, but can u recommend me one of it? )